# не запускается отладчик в подключенном модуле ассемблера в visual studio 2019

Tags: отладка, visual-studio-2019, masm32, masm

Пишу, получается, многомодульное приложение(С++ и язык ассемблера), ставлю точку останова в модуле - не отлаживает, в основном cpp-файле - отлаживает. То есть он пролетает и консоль выкидывает сообщение, что всё успешно завершено. Конфигурация сборки и участие файла в проекте настроил. че делать?

Comment: А отладочная информация имеется?

Comment: получается, нет

Answer (score 0):

тебе нужно чтобы в момент отладки активным было окно с дизассемблерным кодом, тогда шаг отладки будет отсчитывается для него.

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: поставь точку отладки сперва в c++ коде, когда она остановиться перейди в окно дизассемблера и отлаживай уже там.

Comment: просто весь прикол в том, что до этого был другой проект и там всё работало

Comment: чтобы понять причину нужно больше информации, в идеале вообще сесть рядом и запустить. так что скорей всего это так и останется тайной.

Answer (score 0):

При сборке ассемблера следует включить генерацию отладочной информации посредством опций `/Zd` `/Zi`. Иначе отладчик не будет знать, какие строки в исходном файле чему соответствуют.